# two slicknav used at the same time

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, slicknav

Is it possible to have two slicknav on one page?
I'm planning to create something like this menu for mobile.

I'll be having a slicknav menu outside when I clicked the "MENU" it's submenu will be (A propos, Multimedia and Partenaires) while inside the menu will be have 3 main links with submenu also.
[image]
Example Code

```
<div class="main-menu-wrapper">
   <div class="main-menu-inner>
     <ul>
       <li>Les Concours
         <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Programmation
         <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Espace Pro
         <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>

   <ul>
      <li>A propos</li>
      <li>Multimedia</li>
      <li>Partenaires</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```